# Running nodemon inside Docker doesn't exit immediately upon Ctrl+C interrupt

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, signals, nodemon

My project uses nodemon inside Docker. It runs perfectly, but when I stop the process from my terminal with Ctrl+C, the container doesn't get turned off immediately. Instead, I have to wait for exactly 10 seconds before Docker finally kills it.

I've reduced the problem in my project to the following minimum reproducible example.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  node:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-bullseye-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

package.json:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "docker compose up --build",
        "start": "nodemon src/script.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
    }
}
```

src/script.js (doesn't really matter):

```js
console.log("Hello world!");
```

When I execute `npm run dev`, everything goes smoothly:

```
$ npm run dev

> dev
> docker compose up --build

[+] Building 0.1s (9/9) FINISHED                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [node internal] load .dockerignore                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                       0.0s
 => [node internal] load build definition from Dockerfile             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 136B                                  0.0s
 => [node internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-bull  0.0s
 => [node 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-bullseye-slim           0.0s
 => [node internal] load build context                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 183B                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [node 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [node 3/4] COPY package.json .                             0.0s
 => CACHED [node 4/4] RUN npm i                                       0.0s
 => [node] exporting to image                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                               0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:49c76459b45682e7c3fd7005371f53df516b52ee  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-node                          0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container test-node-1  Recreated                                   0.1s 
Attaching to test-node-1
test-node-1  | 
test-node-1  | > start
test-node-1  | > nodemon src/script.js
test-node-1  | 
test-node-1  | [nodemon] 3.0.2
test-node-1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
test-node-1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
test-node-1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
test-node-1  | [nodemon] starting `node src/script.js`
test-node-1  | Hello world!
test-node-1  | [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

…but then when I press Ctrl+C to exit, I have to wait 10 seconds:

```
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Aborting on container exit...
[+] Stopping 1/1
 ✔ Container test-node-1  Stopped                                    10.1s 
canceled
```

My guess is that nodemon fails to trap the SIGINT signal and doesn't act on it. How do I fix this?

Here's a GitHub repo with the example, so you can quickly reproduce this locally and test: https://github.com/hdodov/mcve-nodemon-docker-exit

Comment: Is Docker actually necessary to your application, particularly if you already have a Node environment on the host?  Can you run `npm run start` locally, and skip Docker entirely?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I need Docker, because I have a dependency called "sharp" which can have unexpected behaviors on different platforms. I also want to get as close as I can to our production setup.